# Footer element keeps shrinking in height

Tags: html, css

Why would a `footer` element shrink in `height` when the height of the browser window shrinks?

---

I have tried to setup a fiddle with all of my code, but it is not reproducible within JSFiddle so I will not post the fiddle.

My `footer` code is:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 7px;

    background-color: silver;
}
```

and its HTML is:

```
<footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2014&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;
            <a href="~/Disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
            <a href="PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="TermsOfUse">Terms of Use</a>
    </p>
</footer>
```

Some things to note:

- I have set `min-height: 30px;` to the `footer` element, but this still does not stop it from shrinking in height.
- I now have a migraine.

Comment: it's work for me http://jsfiddle.net/wPmv3/

Comment: `I will not post the fiddle` How could we help then? The posted code seems fine.

Comment: do you have `height:100%` on your body? if so when you shrink the window is it pushing the footer off the bottom rather than shrinking it?

Comment: Exactly my point. The code seems fine, and I think the code is actually fine. But what's the point in posting the fiddle when the result inside the fiddle does not equal the result that I am experiencing? You won't have anything to base it off. In this case, the fiddle is just as useless as this code. I will post the fiddle since it's been asked for incase I am wrong.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/yat2T/

Comment: @Pete you are spot on. Thanks so much! If you wanna put that as an answer, I will accept. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the fiddles. I don't see the footer shrinking in the fiddles but I will definitely post code next time, since you are able to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have your height set to 100% on your body, it sounds as if when the window shrinks it will push the footer off the bottom of the screen.  Try changing your height to min-height.

If you are having troubles with keeping the footer at the bottom of the screen try googling sticky footer and that may help you find a solution to keep the footer at the bottom